# Authorize end point of B2C taking 2-3 seconds in India

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am invoking the authorization end point of AzureB2C using a mobile APP but finding it slow.  I am not finding a handle to improve the performance

I see the java script in the authorize end point response containing javascript which has not been used a minify or compressed.  Also it refer some static javascript files which are not picked from a CDN.  Could this be a reason it is taking around 2 seconds ?

Can someone suggest how I can tune AzureB2C to get the Authorize end point response less than 2 second. From a mobile app loading the (Azureb2c) login screen is now taking 2 seconds any help in reducing it would be appreciated .

Comment: Hi @srini. Where are you hosting the content files?

Comment: We have moved the content displayed on the Sigin Page to the CDN.  We still have the jquery-bundle-1.1.02min.js appears to be downloading directly.  Also in the Authorize end point we are seeing a response time varying from .6 mili seconds to 2 second.  Is there any way to optimize the authorize call and reduce the time taken to download the jquery-bundle.

Comment: We are seeing the b2c endpoints having variable response times in India.  We see in the US they perform much better.  What could be the reason ?